# How to run two applications using the same database on Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat8.5

I have two Spring Boot applications which are using the same database,
I deploy them on tomcat.
I am not enable to run them at the same time !!
I have to start only one application!!

I send you 2 screenshots to see more my problem:
[image]

as you can see here one application is started

If I click start on the second application: (GestionRetardApplication-0.0.1)
I get the following error:
[image]

```
ECHEC - L'application pour le chemin de contexte [/GestionRetardApplication-0.0.1] n'a pas pu être démarrée
ECHEC - L'exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GestionRetardApplication-0.0.1]]] a été rencontrée
```

Comment: How you are starting 2 applications ? are you using JAR or WAR ?

Comment: war deployed on Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that both applications are running on the same port, Tomcat cannot be run twice on the same port.

Try adding this to one of your application.properties file

```
server.port=8081
```

or in application.yml file

```
server:
  port : 8081
```

Now the server will start on port 8081, and you will already have the other application on 8080. Both can now connect to the database

Comment: that works like that when you start your application as spring boot application and internally the embeded tomcat is used